# В чем причина неверного отображения русских символов в программе?

Tags: c++

Делаю проект под Qt C++. Есть проблемы с локалью, которую никак не могу решить.

Например, вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом это : `QAction *actionSelectZap = ui->menuBar->addAction(tr("Выбор записи"));`
дает адекватный результат и создает кнопку в баре с русской локалью.
Так же при подхвате текстовых переменных из других программ (логи и пр.) и их выводе тоже всё ок.

Я прочитал много похожих тем с локалью (в основном проблемами с выводом в консоль), но не смог решить свою проблему.

Среда MSVC 2015

upd: Мне важно, чтобы это так же работало адекватно под Linux

```
void QtwContr::contrBox(const char* txt)
{
    // немодальное окно сообщений
    if (txt != nullptr && txt[0] != '\0')
    {
        if(hContr == nullptr) 
            hContr = new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Information,  "WIN_CONTR", "", QMessageBox::NoButton, nullptr);//ptr_wqtRm ? (QWidget*)ptr_wqtRm : (QWidget*)pmainwin_Zapusk); 
            //,Qt::Dialog);
        if (hContr != nullptr)
            {
//          hContr->setParent(ptr_wqtRm ? (QWidget*)ptr_wqtRm : (QWidget*)pmainwin_Zapusk);
            hContr->setModal(false);
            hContr->setText(QString::fromLocal8Bit(txt));
            hContr->show();
            }
    }
    else
        {
        if (hContr != nullptr)
            hContr->hide();
        }
}
```

Comment: просто студия некорректно показывает UTF-8, это проблема студии, но не программы.

Comment: @AlexF у меня некорректно работает программа. Например, я не могу  корректно использовать свой метод `QtwNabl::ifaceContrErr->contrBox("text");` . Он получает на вход 'const char*' . Это обусловлено тем, что часто приходится работать с С-строками. Я не смог провести ни одного удачного преобразования строк (стандартных, Q-строк, С-строк), чтобы передать их в этот метод. На выходе всегда кракозябры - причем они совпадают с содержимым Intellisense. Т.е. я хочу сказать, что это не проблема отображения Intellisense, а проблема кодировки, судя по всему. Либо я что-то не догоняю(что возможно)

Comment: попробуйте показать такую строку на чем то простом, например, на QLabel.  Большинство Qt функций, которые получают `const char*`, обычно там ожидают увидеть ascii. А все остальное им не интересно. что такое QtwNabl я не знаю (и гугл тоже), поэтому, утверждать, правильно ли оно понимает utf-8 или нет - не  могу

Comment: @KoVadim добавил описание функции, можете посмотреть. Основное это `hContr->setText(QString::fromLocal8Bit(txt));`.  Я не понимаю, почему это не работает. Я попробовал сделать `hContr->setText(QString::fromUtf8(txt));` и это помогло. Но мне не понятно, почему он не работает с первым вариантом. Ибо в некоторых местах (в других функциях) оно работает исправно. Теперь интересно, будет ли работать `hContr->setText(QString::fromUtf8(txt));` в линуксе

Comment: `QtwNabl::ifaceContrErr->contrBox(u8"текст");`

Comment: @PavelGridin с `QString::fromLocal8Bit` не работает. С `QString::fromUtf8` работает и без `u8`

Comment: fromLocal8Bit использует системную кодировку. В случае винды это скорее всего cp1251, но точно не utf-8. А эти две кодировки внутри отличаются существенно. Когда же Вы выбрали QString::fromUtf8 - оно конечно будет работать, так как входной массив содержал код в кодировке utf-8. Будет ли это работать в линксе? если текст приходит в utf-8, то да, будет работать без проблем.

Comment: если текст останется в 1251, то в линуксе надо будет gcc указать опцию для преобразования 1251 в utf8, ну и qtcreator-у указать, что текст в 1251, чтобы можно было редактировать

Comment: @Artem.rtv, а сам файл с кодом, где строки с кириллицей, в какой кодировке? utf-8?

Comment: @KoVadim благодарю!

Comment: @PavelGridin Учту, спасибо!

Comment: @gil9red , если я правильно вижу, то Юникод

Comment: @Artem.rtv юникод - это не кодировка, если что:)